# Installed applications not working after upgrade to 13.04

Tags: apt, upgrade

I just upgraded from 12.04 to 13.04 and now none of my installed applications work.  A few of the affected programs include ktorrent, chrome, and deluge.  Apt says that I already have the newest version installed but starting from the command line that the program is not currently installed and directs me to use apt-get to install.

I suspect that the programs are installed but Ubuntu doesn't know they are installed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Ryan

Comment: What do you mean by "none"? Can you start gedit for example? Are there any programs that run or is really everything broken? In this case i really would reinstall the whole system with a new/stable version freshly downloaded from the ubuntu site...

Comment: also it may be helpful if you try to run e.g. chrome by typing the command in a terminal and let us know what the errors are. =)

Answer (score 1):

Check in Ubuntu Software Center or Synaptic Package Manager. The installed programs are marked. If you use Synaptic (it's quite fast), click the search button instead of using the default search box (it's buggy). You can re-install a package even if it shows as installed.
Also run `sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get update` prior to that.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try repairing the broken packages in synaptic!
If this doesn't work, try to reinstall the programs completely.